# Bash cut pattern

Tags: bash

I need to cut and save exact pattern in a variable.

`one_two_three_four_five`

`one_two_three_four_five_six..._ten`

I need to cut always beginning `one_` and end `_five_*` and more of variable

result: `two_three_four`

Answer (score 2):

For a pure `bash` solution, one might use [shell parameter expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion), namely [substring removal](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/pe#substring_removal).

For example, the script:

```
#!/bin/bash

var='one_two_three_four_five_six..._ten'
without_prefix="${var#one_}"
without_prefix_and_suffix="${without_prefix%_five*}"

echo "$without_prefix_and_suffix"
```

will produce:

```
two_three_four
```

Note you can't strip both prefix and suffix in a single line, since parameter expansion always acts on a parameter (variable, not expansion).

Answer (score 1):

It's useful to learn `cut` command:

```
echo "one_two_three_four_five_six..._ten" | cut -d'_' -f2-4
two_three_four
```